# Probability that two balls have different colours

Tags: probability, statistics

An urn contains u blue balls and w black balls, with u$\geq$w. A sample of two balls is selected at random from the urn. Prove that the probability that the balls which were picked up to have different colours is 0,5 if and only if there exists k, a positive integer such that $u=\frac{k^2+3k+2}{2}$ and $w=\frac{k^2+k}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint to help you start:

- The probability both are blue is $\dfrac{u(u-1)}{(u+w)(u+w-1)}$
- The probability both are black is $\dfrac{w(w-1)}{(u+w)(u+w-1)}$

*If* is easier than *only if*: for *only if*, you might note that $\frac{k^2+3k+2}{2} - \frac{k^2+k}{2} = k+1$.

Comment: How do I get these relations?

Comment: The probability the first ball is blue is $\frac{u}{u+w}$.  Given the first is blue, the probability the second is also blue is $\frac{u-1}{u+w-1}$.  Then multiply

Comment: Tried everything but didn't reach the end. How to write the probability that the balls have different colours?

Comment: The probability they are different plus the probability they are the same is one, so the probability they are different is $1-\dfrac{u(u-1)}{(u+w)(u+w-1)}-\dfrac{w(w-1)}{(u+w)(u+w-1)}=\dfrac{2uw}{(u+w)(u+w-1)}$